# Remove Content Type Hub URL

Tags: 2010, powershell, content-type-hub

I used a Powershell script to add the URL for the Content Type hub, as in the picture below.

[image: Set the URL for the content type hub]

Now I wish to remove this URL. Not replace it, but remove it altogether using PowerShell.

Is this possible? Using the same command with an empty URL did not work.

(Set-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Identity $mms -hubURI "")